Passing in API data before calling child component React Native (TypeScript)
I am trying to make an API call in my parent component and pass that data to the child component but I think the child component is getting rendered before the API call is complete and I'm receiving undefined data in my child component.
Specifically, the error is:
Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0):  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object
I want to wait for the API call to finish then use that data to pass it on to my child.
Here's the parent:
const Parent = () => {
    ...
    const [intraday, setIntraday] = useState<IntradayInterface>();
    const [daily, setDaily] = useState<DailyInterface>();
    const [weekly, setWeekly] = useState<WeeklyInterface>();
    const [monthly, setMonthly] = useState<MonthlyInterface>();

    useEffect(() => {
      async function UpdateDetails()
      {
          const intradayJSON = await getIntradayData(newSymbol);
          const dailyJSON = await getDailyData(newSymbol);
          const weeklyJSON = await getWeeklyData(newSymbol);
          const monthlyJSON = await getMonthlyData(newSymbol);
      
          setIntraday(parseIntradayData(intradayJSON));          
          setDaily(parseDailyData(dailyJSON));
          setWeekly(parseWeeklyData(weeklyJSON));
          setMonthly(parseMonthlyData(monthlyJSON));
           
          setIsLoading(false);
      }
      UpdateStockDetails();
    }, []); 

    if(isLoading){
      return <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
    }
    else{
      return (
        <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: black}}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', padding: 10 }}>
          <View>
              <Graph symbol={newSymbol} 
                intraday={intraday!}
                daily={daily!}
                weekly={weekly!}
                monthly={monthly!}/>
          </View>
...


And the child is my Graph component.
Is there anyway I can make the parent wait for the api call to finish so I can pass on the result data to the child Graph component?

You can conditionally render the Graph component when all the props it needs are available. You should also surround any asynchronous logic in a try/catch in order to handle thrown exceptions and rejected Promises.
Example:
const Parent = () => {
  ...
  const [intraday, setIntraday] = useState<IntradayInterface>();
  const [daily, setDaily] = useState<DailyInterface>();
  const [weekly, setWeekly] = useState<WeeklyInterface>();
  const [monthly, setMonthly] = useState<MonthlyInterface>();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function updateDetails() {
      try {
        const [intradayJSON, dailyJSON, weeklyJSON, monthlyJSON] =
          await Promise.all([
            getIntradayData(newSymbol),
            getDailyData(newSymbol),
            getWeeklyData(newSymbol),
            getMonthlyData(newSymbol)
          ]);
      
        setIntraday(parseIntradayData(intradayJSON));          
        setDaily(parseDailyData(dailyJSON));
        setWeekly(parseWeeklyData(weeklyJSON));
        setMonthly(parseMonthlyData(monthlyJSON));
      } catch(error) {
        // catch and handle/ignore errors/rejections
      } finally {
        // Clear loading status regardless of success/failure
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }

    updateStockDetails();
  }, []);

  const canShowGraph = newSymbol && intraday && daily && weekly && monthly;

  if (isLoading) {
    return <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
  } else {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: black }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            padding: 10
          }}
        >
          <View>
            {canShowGraph && (
              <Graph
                symbol={newSymbol} 
                intraday={intraday}
                daily={daily}
                weekly={weekly}
                monthly={monthly}
              />
            )}
          </View>
          ...
        </View>
        ...
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
};

It may also be a good idea to render some fallback UI in case the loading does fail and there isn't graph data to pass as props.
Example:
<View>
  {canShowGraph ? (
    <Graph
      symbol={newSymbol} 
      intraday={intraday}
      daily={daily}
      weekly={weekly}
      monthly={monthly}
    />
  ) : <View>No data.</View>}
</View>


Sorry I'm new to typescript and react so didn't know you can just add a flag like that, very helpful! Thanks!

@RizwanSiddiqui Ah, that's nothing to apologize about, we all started fresh at one point or another. In that case you may care to read specifically about Conditional Rendering, and since you are new to React you should probably read through the Getting Started guide and the rest of the React docs to gain familiarity.
